# point at wrong z-coordinate at with matplotlib scatter plot function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot this simple set of points using matplotlib's scatter plot function (Python 2.7, Spyder GUI):

```
X=[0 0 1 1]
Y=[0 1 0 1]
Z=[0 1 1 1]
```

This actually represent the OR operator, so I'd like to have a different marker/color for the point for which z = 0. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

X = np.zeros( (4,1) )
X[0,0] = 0
X[1,0] = 0
X[2,0] = 1
X[3,0] = 1

Y = np.zeros( (4,1) )
Y[0,0] = 0
Y[1,0] = 1
Y[2,0] = 0
Y[3,0] = 1

Z = np.zeros( (4,1) )
Z[0,0] = 0
Z[1,0] = 1
Z[2,0] = 1
Z[3,0] = 1

for i in range(0,len(Z)):

    if Z[i]:
        ax.scatter(X[i],Y[i],Z[i],'x',color="r")

    else:
        ax.scatter(X[i],Y[i],Z[i],'o',color="b")

ax.view_init(elev=0., azim=200)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
```

This is the plot I get:

[image]

Clearly, the red point in the middle at the bottom should be at the top left-hand side corner of the plot.

Is there a problem with my code or could it be an issue with matplotlib?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitely set the marker argument as `marker='x'` instead of a positional argument.

```
ax.scatter(X[i],Y[i],Z[i],marker='x',color="r")
```

This will result in the desired plot.

[image]

The reason for this is that otherwise `"x"` will be interpreted as the `zdir` argument, setting the plane for a 2D scatter plot.